App giving SIGABRT after upgrading mac and xcode from version 14.1 to xcode version 15.3
I have recently upgraded my system and xcode version to 15.4 to implement the aws code artifact pull.
The code was running fine on xcode 14.3.
The code is giving crash SIGABRT on runinng the same code on xcode 15.3
It is occuring error when calling:
Task {
            let isUserSigned = await AWSS3Manager.shared.fetchCurrentAuthSession()
            print("auth session value =", isUserSigned)
    }

Traces:

(lldb) bt
* thread #8, queue = 'com.apple.NSURLSession-work', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x000000020aa421f0
    frame #1: 0x000000020aa66dcc
    frame #2: 0x000000020aa9b980
    frame #3: 0x000000020aa92fc8
    frame #4: 0x000000020a8bb7f0
    frame #5: 0x000000020a8bba58
    frame #6: 0x000000020a8b666c
    frame #7: 0x000000020a8ba4c8
    frame #8: 0x000000020a8b91dc
    frame #9: 0x0000000180a186e0 Foundation`merged closure #1 (Swift.Optional<Foundation.Data>, Swift.Optional<__C.NSURLResponse>, Swift.Optional<Swift.Error>) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.CheckedContinuation<(Foundation.Data, __C.NSURLResponse), Swift.Error>) -> () in closure #1 () async throws -> (Foundation.Data, __C.NSURLResponse) in __C.NSURLSession.data(for: Foundation.URLRequest, delegate: Swift.Optional<__C.NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>) async throws -> (Foundation.Data, __C.NSURLResponse) + 124
    frame #10: 0x0000000180a1d440 Foundation`merged partial apply forwarder for closure #1 (Swift.Optional<Foundation.Data>, Swift.Optional<__C.NSURLResponse>, Swift.Optional<Swift.Error>) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.CheckedContinuation<(Foundation.Data, __C.NSURLResponse), Swift.Error>) -> () in closure #1 () async throws -> (Foundation.Data, __C.NSURLResponse) in __C.NSURLSession.upload(for: Foundation.URLRequest, from: Foundation.Data, delegate: Swift.Optional<__C.NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>) async throws -> (Foundation.Data, __C.NSURLResponse) + 88
    frame #11: 0x0000000180a17514 Foundation`reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Swift.Optional<Foundation.Data>, @guaranteed Swift.Optional<__C.NSURLResponse>, @guaranteed Swift.Optional<Swift.Error>) -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned Swift.Optional<__C.NSData>, @unowned Swift.Optional<__C.NSURLResponse>, @unowned Swift.Optional<__C.NSError>) -> () + 120
    frame #12: 0x0000000184316e78 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol2673 + 476
    frame #13: 0x0000000184332c98 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol3272 + 152
    frame #14: 0x0000000184332b58 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol3270 + 172
    frame #15: 0x000000018431c254 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol2811 + 388
    frame #16: 0x000000018431c244 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol2811 + 372
    frame #17: 0x0000000184543bfc CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol14796 + 200
    frame #18: 0x00000001843303a8 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol3176 + 528
    frame #19: 0x000000018439f1b8 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol5215 + 104
    frame #20: 0x000000018439ec78 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol5210 + 100
    frame #21: 0x000000018439ef8c CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol5211 + 720
    frame #22: 0x000000010b2bde4c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104
    frame #23: 0x000000010b2ad73c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #24: 0x000000010b2b5a30 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 916
    frame #25: 0x000000010b2b6774 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 420
    frame #26: 0x000000010b2c31a8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 324
    frame #27: 0x000000010b2c2604 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 488
    frame #28: 0x000000010ab8b814 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 284

Any help or insights will be highly appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!

The issue was some build settings error like base sdk and deployment version. Fixing them make the code run successfully.
